# MySQL Call Procedure in Function ERROR

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, mysqli

I am trying to get the count from a procedure result. I have seen that you can create a temporary table and count it later. But when I add my procedure to the function, it stops working. Why is that?

```
  $connection->query('
   drop procedure if exists parents;
   create procedure parents(in parent int(11),in name varchar(22))
   begin
    set @parent=parent;
    drop temporary table if exists ids;
    create temporary table ids(id int(11));
    while @parent<>0 do
     prepare statement from concat("select related into @parent from ",name," where id=?");
     execute statement using @parent;
     insert into ids(id) values(@parent);
    end while;
    select*from ids;
   end;
   drop function if exists counted;
   create function counted(parent int(11),name varchar(22))
   returns int(11)
   begin
    call parents(parent,name);
    return (select count(*) from ids);
   end;
   ');
   $fetch=$connection->query('select counted(3,"category");')->fetchall();
```

I get a fetch boolean error.

Comment: You can't execute multiple statements in a single call to `query()` in mysqli.

Answer (score 1):

You can't execute multiple queries in a single call to `query()` (you can do it with `multi_query()`, but you can't customize the query delimiter to distinguish between the `;` that separates queries and the ones used inside the procedure). So split this into multiple queries.

```
  $connection->query('xdrop procedure if exists parents');
  $connection->query('
   create procedure parents(in parent int(11),in name varchar(22))
   begin
    set @parent=parent;
    drop temporary table if exists ids;
    create temporary table ids(id int(11));
    while @parent<>0 do
     prepare statement from concat("select related into @parent from ",name," where id=?");
     execute statement using @parent;
     insert into ids(id) values(@parent);
    end while;
    select*from ids;
   end;
  ');
  $connection->query('drop function if exists counted');
  $connection->query('
   create function counted(parent int(11),name varchar(22))
   returns int(11)
   begin
    call parents(parent,name);
    return (select count(*) from ids);
   end;
   ');
   $fetch=$connection->query('select counted(3,"category");')->fetchall();
```

Comment: But mine executes all of them.

Comment: What is the error message? When `query()` returns a boolean `false`, you should print `$connection->error`.